# How to use PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

can you help me please?

I have this:

```
| NCuota | Cuenta  | Capital|Interes | IVA | Seguro| Comisión | ImpuestoComis | VCuota|
| 1      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 2      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 3      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 4      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 5      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 6      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 7      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 8      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 9      | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 10     | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 11     | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
| 12     | 123     |    100 |50      |5    |3      |1         |1              |160    |
```

With this query:

```
select 
ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY a.PPFPAG ASC) as NCuota, ppcta as Cuenta, 
a.ppcap as Capital, a.ppint as Interes, a.ppiint as IVA, ppimp11 as Seguro, e.Pp002Imp as Comision, e.Pp002Aux1 as ImpuestoComision,
(a.ppcap + a.ppint + a.ppiint + ppimp11 + e.Pp002Imp + Pp002Aux1) as Vcuota
From fsd601 a (nolock), fsd611 b (nolock), fsd010 c (nolock), fsr008 d (nolock), fpp002 e (nolock), x054023 f (nolock) 
where a.pgcod=b.pgcod and a.ppmod=b.ppmod and a.ppsuc=b.ppsuc and a.ppmda=b.ppmda and a.pppap=b.pppap 
and a.ppcta=b.ppcta  and a.ppoper=b.ppoper  and a.ppsbop=b.ppsbop  and a.pptope=b.pptope and a.ppfpag=b.ppfpag 
and a.pgcod=c.pgcod and a.ppmod=c.aomod and a.ppsuc=c.aosuc and a.ppmda=c.aomda and a.pppap=c.aopap 
and a.ppcta=c.aocta and a.ppoper=c.aooper and a.ppsbop=c.aosbop and a.pptope=c.aotope and c.aostat=0 
and c.aocta=d.ctnro and d.petdoc in (1,3) and cttfir='T' and a.ppmod=e.ppmod and a.ppsuc=e.ppsuc and a.ppmda=e.ppmda
and a.pppap=e.pppap and a.ppcta=e.ppcta and a.ppoper=e.ppoper and a.ppsbop=e.ppsbop and a.pptope=e.pptope 
and a.ppfpag=e.ppfpag and e.PrestConc=6 and a.ppmod=f.xllaomod and a.ppsuc=f.xllaosuc and a.ppmda=f.xllaomda 
and a.pppap=f.xllaopap and a.ppcta=f.xllaocta and a.ppoper=f.xllaooper and a.ppsbop=f.xllaosbop and a.pptope=f.xllaotop 
and c.aocta=63658 and c.aooper=333718
```

But i really need this and i don't know how :/

```
| Cuenta | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 123    |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |160 |
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: `From fsd601 a (nolock), fsd611 b (nolock), ...` - use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax, and don't litter your queries with `NOLOCK` (they're not magic go-faster hints).

Comment: If you really need *read uncommtted* on every table, why not just set the *transaction isolation level*? I would *guess* you really don't if data integrity is of any concern here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  Cuenta
       ,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
    
from    t
pivot  (max(VCuota) for NCuota in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p
```

| Cuenta | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 | 160 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e9glQYFQ)

Comment: Hi DannySlor. 

I tried this but doesn't work :(

select
ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY a.PPFPAG ASC) as NCuota, ppcta as Cuenta, 
a.ppcap as Capital, a.ppint as Interes, a.ppiint as IVA, ppimp11 as Seguro, e.Pp002Imp as Comision, e.Pp002Aux1 as ImpuestoComision,
(a.ppcap + a.ppint + a.ppiint + ppimp11 + e.Pp002Imp + Pp002Aux1) as Vcuota,
Cuenta,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]
....
....
....
pivot  (max(VCuota) for NCuota in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) p

Comment: you need to nest it in another `select * from t` and it would work.

Comment: Please choose the answer and vote up